# Quotas and limits on received routes in BGP session

Tags: routes, bgp, google-cloud-router

Are there any limits on the number of routes received on BGP session in Google Cloud Router?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could edit your question to add a bit more info on your setup? How exactly do you use BGP sessions? This would help others to give you a more tailored answer.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming-related questions. Questions about how a third-party service works should generally be directed to that third-party's customer service. Although in this case, ServerFault may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of unique destinations for learned routes on Cloud Router have 2 different limits depending if:

- Cloud Routers are in the same region.
- Cloud Routers are from different regions.

Default limit is 100 learned routes on both of these, you can find the details on [Cloud router limits doc](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/router/quotas#limits).

If you need more you can do route summarization to reduce the number of routes advertised on the remote peer or contact your Google Cloud sales team to request a limit increase as pointed on the limits documentation.